# Prevent Marker Clustering for Small Clusters in Leaflet MarkerCluster with GeoJSON

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using MarkerCluster for Leaflet in conjunction with GeoJSON. My goal is to prevent the clustering of markers when the cluster's children size is less than 50, and instead, display all the individual markers.

I've attempted to handle this scenario within the iconCreateFunction without success. My intention is to maintain the default zoom interactions with MarkerCluster for other scenarios but to specifically "cancel" clustering when the cluster size is less than 50.

Do you have any suggestions or examples on how I can achieve this behavior without disrupting other MarkerCluster functionalities?